# Why is specific Java library not being found by java on linux command line

Tags: java, jar, external, libraries

This should be straight forward yet I do not see why the commons-logging-1.2.jar is not being located after an apparently successful compile. But I am not sure why the commons-logging-1.2.jar library not being found by java when it is run this way.

```
$ javac -classpath commons-logging-1.2:pdfbox-2.0.24.jar:xmpbox-2.0.24.jar org/example/app/App.java
$ jar cfm app.jar MANIFEST.MF ./org/example/app/App.class
$ java -cp ./* -jar app.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class ..commons-logging-1.2.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: //commons-logging-1/2/jar
```

I also tried running as:

```
$ java -cp ./* org.example.app.App
Error: Could not find or load main class ..commons-logging-1.2.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: //commons-logging-1/2/jar
```

I intend to ultimately use Maven, but for now I just want to be able to understand the process manually. I was able to get this to compile and run on Windows using the same setup (folders/tools/etc).  Not sure what I am missing here.

All java commands are run from the dir where org/example/app is located. And the jar files are located in the same directory. So I have all jars (including the app.jar when it was created) in dir A and under dir A is where org/example/app/App.class is created.

I purposely did an incremental build where first, pdfbox was only included and receive the appropriate error that xmpbox classes were missing. Then I added xmpbox. Yet when I did not add commons-logging-1.2.jar in the class path, there were no errors reported.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try putting an `echo` in front of that command and see what it expands to.

Comment: I tried that and still same results - they expanded properly to the jars. I now put them in a lib dir and still same thing. Its expanding and finding the jars it seems, but not the commons-logging jar. Also, it looks like the same jar is being interpreted two different way - one starting with ..lib and the other //lib (and also the one ends with -1.2.jar while the other is 1/2/jar

Comment: Btw - I fixed the typo early on (the one with commons-logging missing the jar extension)...so that is not what is the cause at this time.

Comment: Take a look again, and compare the syntax of `-cp` with the output from `echo`.

Comment: That showed me what I needed - Tx!  When I expanded it, it was placing spaces between the jar file names and -cp needs : between each name under linux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following, commented on by user chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic solved the problem.

> "Try putting an echo in front of that command and see what it expands
> to."

After trying that suggestion it showed that the expansion was causing the problem. Under Windows I did not use expansion but under linux, when looking at the expansion it showed that there were spaces between the filenames instead of ":" as required by the -cp syntax.

Comment: The _root cause_ of this is that in Windows, `*` is _passed to the program_ and expanded there, but in Unix, `*` is expanded _by the shell_ and passed as a series of arguments.

Comment: Thank  you for the clarification. This will definitely be useful going forward on this project.